# Paypal Payment issue regarding credit card number and type

Tags: paypal, payment

Facing issue...

I have added below details while testing in sandbox but i am getting this error:

Code Credit Card:

```
$cardDetails->CreditCardNumber = "4032039141982290";
$cardDetails->CreditCardType = "Visa";
$cardDetails->ExpMonth = "12";
$cardDetails->ExpYear = "2018";
$cardDetails->CVV2 = "123";
$cardDetails->CardOwner = "BILAL";
```

ERROR:

```
Payment - Failed
This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
Error msg - This transaction cannot be processed. 
Please enter a valid credit card number and type.
```

Please anyone let me know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue been resolved...
This issue was coming as i don't enable account type to "Pro"..
Once you will shift the business account to "PRO", error stops showing...